# Error in mounted hook: "Error: The FullCalendar view "dayGridMonth" does not exist. Make sure your plugins are loaded correctly."

Tags: typescript, fullcalendar, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have created a vue+dotnet core project with following this [repo](https://github.com/SoftwareAteliers/asp-net-core-vue-starter). The project uses typescript for vue. Now, i want to add [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue) to my project. But when i run the project, i got the exception(Error in mounted hook: "Error: The FullCalendar view "dayGridMonth" does not exist. Make sure your plugins are loaded correctly.") in browser console.

**Schedule.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-slide-y-transition mode="out-in">
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
            <FullCalendar :weekends="false" defaultView="dayGridMonth" :plugins="calendarPlugins" :events="fsEvents"/>
        </v-col> 
      </v-row>
    </v-slide-y-transition>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Flow from '@/components/Flow.vue';

@Component({
    components: {
        Flow,
        FullCalendar,
    },
    props: {
        fsEvents: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => {
                return [{ title: 'event 1', date: '2020-04-01' }, { title: 'event 2', date: '2020-04-02' }];
            },
        },
    },
    data: () => {
        return { calendarPlugins: dayGridPlugin };
    },
})

export default class ScheduleView extends Vue { }
</script>

<style lang='scss'>
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
</style>
```

How should i load the plugin for fullcalendar comopnent in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution. The calendarPlugins in the data should be an array while not an object. Following code resolved my problem.

```
@Component({
    components: {
        Flow,
        FullCalendar,
    },
    props: {
        fsEvents: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => {
                return [{ title: 'event 1', date: '2020-04-01' }, { title: 'event 2', date: '2020-04-02' }];
            },
        },
    },
    data: () => {
        return { calendarPlugins: [dayGridPlugin] };
    },
})
```